# save user session in localstorage in React server side application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, react-redux

In my app I want to save the user `session_id` in local storage. My app is written with React and Redux ( With server side rendering ). I fetch user `session_id` from Api. I want to save session_id while user is logged in to my app ? 
How is the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the `session_id` to local storage when you receive it from the server. Then in your application initialization file check if the local storage contains any `session_id`. If so, use that id to fetch user data.

As local storage is client side (browser) feature, you can't use it in backend.

Another option could be to save your `session_id` into cookie and read that cookie in server side. That way you could authenticate the user already in server side.

Comment: I got window object is undefined. Because my app run in the server.

Comment: yeah, you should check if that exists before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code you currently have to understand your question a little better. From what I understood you want to maybe try the code below. In the else statement make the api request for the session id and then setItem with the session id that came from the api request. You will then have access to it with a variable called currentSessionId.

```
    var currentSessionId;

    if(localStorage.getItem('session_id')){
        currentSessionId = localStorage.getItem('session_id');
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('session_id','<session id>');
        currentSessionId = localStorage.getItem('session_id');
    }
```

Hope this helps!